# AJAX request only works once in IE

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I have this issue, in FF it works great but in IE only works once...
the html is

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="javascript:vote();"/>
</form>
```

the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function vote(){


if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();


  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  }


xmlhttp.open("GET","../php/votes.php",true);
xmlhttp.send(null);

}

</script>
```

and the PHP code is only a update

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","mylog","mypass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('versus',$con);

mysql_query("update picture_vs set votes = votes + 1");


?>
```

any idea?

Comment: What happens the second time?

Comment: Hi! Welcome on SO! You can format your code by putting 4 spaces at the beginning of each line *(the `{}` button on top of the editor does just that)* ; see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more informations ;; I've done it for you, this time :-) ;; I've tried to re-add the `<` you had removed ; feel free to re-edit your question if I messed up something!

Comment: Caching. The request doesn't work the second time, because the browser avoids to load the same thing twice. The common workaround is to append a random id to the url.

Comment: What @mario says... or use [jQuery's ajax functions](http://jquery.com/), which are guaranteed to work across browsers and have a "no caching" option.

Comment: @Pekka - Not true, as I've encountered uri based caching in IE with jQuery's ajax function.

Comment: @65F maybe, but jQuery has an explicit parameter to turn caching off. I think what it does internally is also just adding a random ID in some browsers, but it does so silently. Anyway, +1 for your answer

Comment: @Pekka - Good to know. I'll take another look at the jQuery docs; I was unaware that cache prevention was an optional parameter.

Comment: @65 yup. It's a boolean parameter named `cache`: [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the following line to...

> xmlhttp.open( "GET",
>   "../php/votes.php?random=" +
>   Math.random(), true);

This will prevent IE from caching your request by URI.