# Refresh issue with XMLHTTP

Tags: jsp, xmlhttprequest

-I am new to JSP, I am using XMLHTTP for retrieving data from mySQL database, but after -updating the data, it only shows the previous data not the updated one, please help me to -find out the solution.I have a radio button,

```
<td class="inputs_new"> <div id = "UT2">

                        <%
                        for (int i = 0; i < thinClientName.size(); i++) {

                        %>
                        <input type = "radio"  class = "my-button2"  onclick="get()" id = "thinClnt_rad" name ="thinClnt_rad" value = "<%=thinClientName.get(i)%>" >
                        <% 
                        out.println(thinClientName.get(i));
                        }
                        %>



    </div> 

     //Get function

      function get()
        {

        var save_thin = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('thinClnt_rad').length; i++)
       {
            if (document.getElementsByName('thinClnt_rad')[i].checked)
            {
                 save_thin =  document.getElementsByName('thinClnt_rad')[i].value;
            }
        }   

            var xmlhttp=  GetXmlHttpObject1();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {

                var respTest = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var res = respTest.split(";");

                document.getElementById("thinClientName").value=res[0];
                document.getElementById("Model").value=res[1];
                document.getElementById("SrNo").value=res[2];
                document.getElementById("ProductID").value=res[3];
                document.getElementById("sprNo").value=res[4];
                document.getElementById("MacAdd").value=res[5];
                document.getElementById("IPAdd").value=res[6];
                document.getElementById("Script").value=res[7];
             document.getElementById("VedName").value =res[10] ;
                document.getElementById("playtime").value = res[11] ;

                 var sid_2=res[8];

    var options= document.getElementById('lstLocation').options;

    for (var i= 0; i <options.length ; i++)
         {
             if (options[i].text==sid_2) {

                document.getElementById("lstLocation").selectedIndex = i; 
            }
        }


      var sid_21=res[9];

    var options= document.getElementById('state').options;

    for (var i= 0; i <options.length ; i++)
         {
             if (options[i].text==sid_21) {

                document.getElementById("state").selectedIndex = i; 
            }
        } 


            }

              }


            xmlhttp.open("GET","GetData.jsp?q="+save_thin,true);
            xmlhttp.send(null);

        }
    function GetXmlHttpObject1()
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
           return new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
          return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
     return null;
    }

   // and getData.jsp
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.sql.*" %>

        <%@page import= "jdbc.DBConnection" %>


    <%


            String str=request.getParameter("q");


            try
            {
                DBConnection con_obj    = new DBConnection();
                Connection con = con_obj.getConnection();
                Statement stmtThinInfo = null;
                Statement stmt_play = null;
                ResultSet rsThinInfo = null;
                ResultSet rs_play = null;
                String q =request.getParameter("q");
                stmtThinInfo = con.createStatement();

            rsThinInfo = stmtThinInfo.executeQuery("select * from thinclient_tbl where name = '"+q+"'"); 
            while (rsThinInfo.next())
            {


                stmt_play = con.createStatement();
                rs_play = stmt_play
                        .executeQuery("Select * from thin_videotable where Thin_Client = '"
                        + q + "'");
                String outPut;
                if (rs_play.next()) {

                 outPut =  rsThinInfo.getString("name") + ";" + rsThinInfo.getString("modell") + ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("serialnumber") +  ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("product_id") +  ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("spare_nr")+  ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("MAC-Adresse") +  ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("IP-Adresse") +  ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("script") + ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("location")+ ";"  +  rsThinInfo.getString("state") +  ";" +  rs_play.getString("VideoName") + ";" +  rs_play.getString("Video_time");
                response.getWriter().write(outPut);
    System.out.println(outPut);
                }
                else
                {
                    outPut =  rsThinInfo.getString("name") + ";" + rsThinInfo.getString("modell") + ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("serialnumber") +  ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("product_id") +  ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("spare_nr")+  ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("MAC-Adresse") +  ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("IP-Adresse") +  ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("script") + ";" +  rsThinInfo.getString("location")+ ";"  +  rsThinInfo.getString("state") +  ";" ;
                    response.getWriter().write(outPut);
                    System.out.println(outPut);
                }

            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }



    %>
```

Please check my code and let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: You will need to share some code in order for people to help you.

Comment: i have a radio button,

Comment: You need to edit your question to include code. There is not enough information in your question for people to help you.

Comment: I have edited my question , please check the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX request only works once in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569860/ajax-request-only-works-once-in-ie)

Comment: @Swatipatil Is the issue closed?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying in IE?
As IE is famous for aggressive caching and will return the same result for the same AJAX query until the whole page is refreshed.

You can include a random identifier in the query string.
Try this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","GetData.jsp?q="+save_thin+"&rand="+Math.random(),true);
```

Comment: yes i am trying it in IE.. as usual in Mozilla it runs properly

Comment: Try adding a random identifier (or date+time) in the string which would generate a unique request every time. You can also disable caching if you are using AJAX with jQuery. Please tick the question as answered if it works :)